# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series'

Tags: python, pandas, series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiW8l.png)

Hi!

I receive the error message "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Series'"
I copied the code from a coursebook to try it out as my own did worked, so it should be ok. 
I also tried a new file name, but received the same error, even as in an other solution was naming the file pandas.py.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Don't call your file `pandas.py`

Comment: called it different - still got the same error

Comment: Make sure you delete `pandas.pyc`

Comment: How to ?  What is .pyc?

Comment: it's the pycache, right?

Comment: got it now - thanks!